# Proving that this infinite series is finite.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $1<r<\infty$ and let $x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_i, \cdots \in \mathbb{R}.$
Suppose
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |x_n|^r < \infty$

Why is it that 
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{|x_n|}{n} < \infty$?

Comment: One option is to use the [*Hölder's inequality*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality#Counting_measure).

Answer (score 1):

Let $q > 1$ be such that $\frac{1}{r} + \frac{1}{q} = 1$. Then by the [*Young's inequality*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_inequality), we have

$$ \frac{|x_n|}{n} \leq \frac{|x_n|^r}{r} + \frac{1}{qn^q}. $$

Therefore, by the assumption,

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{|x_n|}{n} \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigg( \frac{|x_n|^r}{r} + \frac{1}{qn^q} \bigg) < \infty $$